# How to write a rust ndarray into a HDF5 dataset?

Tags: rust, hdf5

I want to save a rust ndarray into a HDF5 file.

I have the following code (which does not work):

```rust
let data: Vec<[f64; 2]> = data.iter().map(|o| [o.timestamp.amount, o.value.value]).collect();
let signal = ndarray::arr2(&data);
let sig1 = group.new_dataset::<f64>().create(&signal_name, (data.len(), 2))?;
sig1.write(signal)?;  // trait bounds not satisfied??
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Turns out there was a version mismatch. The hdf5 crate required ndarray 0.12 and I used ndarray 0.13..

Answer (score 2):

Well the docs tell me arr2 returns an Array but Dataset::write takes an `Into<ArrayView>>`. It doesn't seem From is implemented for ArrayView, however :

- arrays have a `.view()` method which ought return an ArrayView, so `sig1.write(signal.view)` might work
- ArrayView implements `From<& ArrayBase>`, so `sig1.write(&signal)` might also work

at least if ArrayBase is imported / in scope.